# PHP: display value of PHP variables inside a string

Tags: php

so I have this code and I need to parse the PHP variables inside the string. the `$string` here is a response from an API and I have no control over the output. I need to echo it out and display the value of the variables inside the string to an HTML page.

```
<?php
    $product = "Test Product";
    $lot_number = "123123123";
    
    $string = '<table style="width: 100.378%;" border="\">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 10.4834%;"><strong>Product</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 35.6575%;">$lot_number</td>
    <td style="width: 11.9257%;"><strong>Lot No.</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 41.9335%;">$lot_number</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>';

    echo "$string";

?>
```

This is the output of this code

[image]

and this is the output I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Any idea how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: `echo $string;` The quotes are totally unnecessary

Comment: PHP will only automatically expand a $variable if you use it inside a double quoted string literal example `$var = 'World'; echo "Hello $var";` You have a single quoted string literal

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php This page explains how to do it and also explains the difference between single and double quoted strings.

Comment: I understand how the " and ' works in PHP, but my problem is that, that string comes from an API that I consumed and it was sent in that format.

Comment: If that is the case and you want to replace those with the value, I would use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php): `$string = str_replace('$lot_number', $lot_number, $string);`.

Comment: What are the exact syntax specs? Is there a mechanism to separate variables from literal strings (e.g. `${foo}bar`) or to escape dollar signs?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do it. The simplest way in your current case would be to close and reopen the parts where you will print the php variables. Like `"abc " . $var . " def";`

```php
<?php
    $product = "Test Product";
    $lot_number = "123123123";
    
    $string = '<table style="width: 100.378%;" border="\">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 10.4834%;"><strong>Product</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 35.6575%;">'. $product . '</td>
    <td style="width: 11.9257%;"><strong>Lot No.</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 41.9335%;">' . $lot_number .'</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>';

    echo "$string";

?>
```

### UPDATE

You can then use the `str_replace` (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) function to fill the variables.

```
<?php
    $product = "Test Product";
    $lot_number = "123123123";
    
    $string = '<table style="width: 100.378%;" border="\">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 10.4834%;"><strong>Product</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 35.6575%;"> $product </td>
    <td style="width: 11.9257%;"><strong>Lot No.</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 41.9335%;"> $lot_number </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>';

    #echo "$string";
    


$string = str_replace('$product', $product, $string);
$string = str_replace('$lot_number' , $lot_number , $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: as I've mentioned in the post, I don't have control over the string as that string format comes from the API.

Comment: @KimCarlo Ok. My mistake for not having read that. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first single quote `'` to double `"` and vice versa.

```
<?php
    $product = "Test Product";
    $lot_number = "123123123";
    
    $string = "<table style='width: 100.378%;' border='\'>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style='width: 10.4834%;'><strong>Product</strong></td>
    <td style='width: 35.6575%;''> $product </td>
    <td style='width: 11.9257%;'><strong>Lot No.</strong></td>
    <td style='width: 41.9335%;''> $lot_number</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>";

    echo $string;

?>
```

Comment: I don't have control over the string. it was sent to me via API

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two variables just use this code:

```
<?php

$product = "Test Product";
$lot_number = "123123123";

$stringFromApi = '<table style="width: 100.378%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10.4834%;"><strong>Product</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 35.6575%;">$lot_number</td>
            <td style="width: 11.9257%;"><strong>Lot No.</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 41.9335%;">$lot_number</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

$search = ['$product', '$lot_number'];
$replace = [$product, $lot_number];
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $stringFromApi);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you use single quotes you cannot add variables inside the string unless you use a curly brace or a dot.

**Note: using the double quotations method is faster than using the using curly braces or a dot.**

If you want to echo a variable and use a single quoted string in php you have to "glue" the parts together.

There are 2 ways to do this, they are both equally as fast and it's just a matter of personal preference what you want to use.

```
<?php

//Double quotations
$car = "mercedes";
echo "the car brand is a $car<br>";
$type = "Question";
echo "Hi! I just posted a {$type}<br>";

//Single quotations
$name = "StackOverFlow";
echo 'Hi! my name is: ' . $name; 
?>
```

Comment: Except the OP's problem was being inside a single quoted string literal :)

Comment: I forgot about that, but it works the same way, except that if you use double quotes you can actually call the variable inside the quotations. This is only shown as an example on how to use it.

Comment: Curly braces don't allow for expansion in single-quoted strings. The output of your code as written is `the car brand is a mercedesHi! my name is: StackOverFlowHi! I just posted a {$type}`

Comment: Wow I never realized that it only worked in double quotes aswell.. My fault!

Comment: I understand how the `"` and `'` works in PHP, but my problem is that, that string comes from an API that I consumed and it was already sent in that format

Answer (score -1):

It works for you.
There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments.

```
<?php
        $product = "Test Product";
        $lot_number = "123123123";
        
        $string = '<table style="width: 100.378%;" border="\">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 10.4834%;"><strong>Product</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 35.6575%;">'.$product.'</td>
        <td style="width: 11.9257%;"><strong>Lot No.</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 41.9335%;">'.$lot_number.'</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>';
    
        echo $string;
    
    ?>
```

For more information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php. Example

```
<?php
$a = '12345';

// This works:
echo "qwe{$a}rty"; // qwe12345rty, using braces
echo "qwe" . $a . "rty"; // qwe12345rty, concatenation used

// Does not work:
echo 'qwe{$a}rty'; // qwe{$a}rty, single quotes are not parsed
echo "qwe$arty"; // qwe, because $a became $arty, which is undefined
?>
```